# Codename One Button css styling issue: shadow over material icon and text color not applying to icon

Tags: css, codenameone, stylesheet

I am trying to style a button with a css style sheet.

There are two undesired side effects when I use material icons: 1) a white shadows appears over the icon and 2) the icon does not change the color with the text color.

Killing line after line, I found out that the shadow seems to be related to the padding. But I couldn't find any hints why the icon color does not change according to the text color.

Here is the code from the css file :

```
ButtonTest {

    background-color: blueviolet;
    box-shadow: 3pt 3pt 10pt 1px rgba(61,59,61,0.4);
    color: red;
    font-family: "native:MainRegular";
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin-top: 75pt;
    margin-left: 40pt;
    margin-right: 20pt;
    padding: 50pt;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Is there a way to avoid this? Any kind help would be appreciated.

This is the generated code:

```
private void initGuiBuilderComponents(com.codename1.ui.util.Resources resourceObjectInstance) {
    setLayout(new com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout());
    setTitle("GuiComponentBuilder");
    setName("GuiComponentBuilder");
    addComponent(gui_Box_Layout_Y);
    gui_Box_Layout_Y.setName("Box_Layout_Y");
    ((com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout)gui_Box_Layout_Y.getParent().getLayout()).setInsets(gui_Box_Layout_Y, "0.0mm -3.054738E-6mm 0.0mm 0.0mm").setReferenceComponents(gui_Box_Layout_Y, "-1 -1 -1 -1").setReferencePositions(gui_Box_Layout_Y, "0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0");
    gui_Box_Layout_Y.addComponent(gui_ButtonTest);
    gui_ButtonTest.setText("Test");
    gui_ButtonTest.setUIID("ButtonTest");
    gui_ButtonTest.setName("ButtonTest");
    com.codename1.ui.FontImage.setMaterialIcon(gui_ButtonTest,'');
    gui_Box_Layout_Y.setName("Box_Layout_Y");
    ((com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout)gui_Box_Layout_Y.getParent().getLayout()).setInsets(gui_Box_Layout_Y, "0.0mm -3.054738E-6mm 0.0mm 0.0mm").setReferenceComponents(gui_Box_Layout_Y, "-1 -1 -1 -1").setReferencePositions(gui_Box_Layout_Y, "0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0");
}// </editor-fold>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code that you use to create this button (not the CSS, but the java).  Likely you're setting the icon before you assign the UIID to the button.  You must set the style before setting the icon or the icon doesn't know what color to make itself.  Of course, this depends on how you did it.  I'd need to see the code

Comment: Steve, both button and icon were added through the GUI BUILDER. No hard coding involved ....

Comment: Nonetheless.  Can you post the generated code in the class so I can see what is being generated?

Comment: Steve, kindly see the generated code above ....

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this.  I created a test project at https://github.com/shannah/cn1-css-bootstrap/, created a gui builder form, and used your style sheet.  Icon shows up red.  No artifact.

Comment: I agree it's a kinda funny phenomenon .. I'm going to download the project and create another one from scratch. If the problem persists, I will contact you again. Many thanks for you help.

Comment: Oh wait... I have managed to reproduce it.  I'll look into this further on Monday

Comment: Great, Steve, looking forward to it ..... Strangely, I can't manage to get icon and text having the same color, when I use a separate css file for styling. Maybe I am applying the wrong process. What I usually do is adding the button and the icon in the Gui Builder, then I add a UIID to the button in the Gui-Builder java file. The result is always a changing text color with the icon color staying  the same ..

Comment: Over the weekend I have been trying a solution and found something that might be of value: styling is possible in parallel both from the css style sheet and the theme builder (theme.css). Yet, when I try to define the box-shadow in the css file, the properties in the theme builder are lost and the shadow appears over the material icon. Defining the text color in the theme builder affects both the text and the icon. When I define the text color form the css file, only the text color changes. Does this help any?

Comment: Steve, does CN1 offer any assistance on the issue or is there no fix for it?

Comment: I have fixed the artifact in the CSS plugin.  https://github.com/shannah/cn1-css/releases/tag/1.1.3